# Windows store app authenticating to WCF protected by ACS

Tags: wcf, windows-8, windows-store-apps, acs

I am working on a windows 8 store app that has to connect to a wcf restful service. the service is currently protected by ACS. Does anyone have a working sample of a win8 client that successfully connects and gets a token from ACS on C#? So far, I have only found the code on windows azure toolkit for windows 8, but it's on javascript and given that it do not know JS, it is pretty much useless to me,

regards

murdockcrc

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  The questions that get the best answers here are ones that include code.  Show us your attempt to solve your problem, tell us what results you're expecting, and what you're getting instead.